# Defining the correct types for an HOC injecting a prop

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components

So I have a set of base components that have its prop types set as:

```
type SomeProps = {
  // ... arbitrary prop types
  theme: {
    wrapper: string,
    button: string,
    // these are also kind of arbitrary
  }
}
```

Now I have an HOC that's going to inject the `theme` prop so users of this newly created component don't/shouldn't have to pass a `theme` prop. Testing showed that the below code won't work though (the merging of types of the same field)...

```
type A = { foo: number };
type B = A & { foo?: number };
const x: B = { foo: 2 };
```

Regardless, I wrote the HOC but I'm not sure the flow types work in the scenario I described. As an additional requirement, the newly created component can still be passed a `theme` prop which should be merged with the injected `theme`. Here's the code for the HOC:

```
// @flow

import withProps from 'recompose/withProps';
import setDisplayName from 'recompose/setDisplayName';
import wrapDisplayName from 'recompose/wrapDisplayName';
import classnames from 'classnames';

type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;
type Component<P> = FunctionComponent<P> | ClassComponent<any, P, any>;

type ThemeType = { [className: string]: string };
type OptionalThemePropType = {
    [prop: string]: mixed,
    theme?: ThemeType
}

function mergeTheme<T, U: T & { theme: ThemeType }>(
    injectedTheme: ThemeType
): (BaseComponent: Component<T>) => Component<U> {
    return BaseComponent => {
        const Themed: Component<U> = withProps((ownProps: OptionalThemePropType) => {
            let theme: ThemeType = injectedTheme;
            if (ownProps && ownProps.theme) {
                const ownTheme: ThemeType = ownProps.theme;
                theme = Object
                    .keys(ownTheme)
                    .filter((key: string) => !!injectedTheme[key])
                    .reduce(
                        (accum: ThemeType, key: string) => {
                            accum[key] = classnames(ownTheme[key], injectedTheme[key]);
                            return accum;
                        },
                        { ...ownTheme, ...injectedTheme }
                    );
            }
            return { theme };
        })(BaseComponent);
        setDisplayName(wrapDisplayName(BaseComponent, 'themed'))(Themed);
        return Themed;
    };
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use `$Diff` flowtype helper to remove injected props from Component Props.

example for withNavigation of @expo/ex-navigation package

```
declare type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
  declare type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;
  declare type Component<P> = FunctionComponent<P> | ClassComponent<any, P, any>;

  declare type ExNavProps = {
    navigation: NavigationContext,
    navigator: ExNavigatorContext,
  };

  declare type WithNavigationOptions = {
    withRef: boolean,
  };

  // withNavigation should add navigator and navigation as defaultprops for WrappedComponent
  declare function withNavigation<DefaultProps, Props, State>(
    WrappedComponent: ClassComponent<DefaultProps, Props, State>,
    options?: WithNavigationOptions,
  ): ClassComponent<DefaultProps & ExNavProps, $Diff<Props, ExNavProps>, State>;
```

however you still need to define ExNavProps in your component, like this

type Props = {
   firstProp: string,
} & ExNavProps

`export default class MyComponent extends React<void, Props, void>`